# Explanation of one part of code c#

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I got c# project from my prof.(no i can't ask him) I understand all except marked part in this class. Can someone give me short explanation or link to answer, what that part of code actually do?

```
class AccessConnection
{
    private OleDbConnection conn;

    public AccessConnection()
    {
        conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString= @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Bata\Desktop\Izvestaj\praksa\praksa\Studenti.accdb";
    }
    public void otvoriKonekciju()
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    public void zatvoriKonekciju()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    /* This is part of code i don't understand
    public OleDbConnection Conn
    {
        get
        {
            return this.conn;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: What about it don't you understand?

Comment: That is called a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties).

Comment: What that part of code actually do in program? @Servy

Comment: In the code you showed us, it's never used. That code makes it available to someone outside the class (which is not a very good idea, IMHO).

Comment: The part will return the oledb connection that is created so you can connect to the database and query it

Comment: It doesn't do anything at all when its commented out.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for link i now understand what it is.

Comment: It makes me a little bit sad that your professor is teaching you to create a new class that wraps a connection object so that you can hard code a connection string. Unfortunately that's normal - even in a "real world" environment you have programmers who do unusual things. 
Bit ćete pametniji od njega.

Answer (score 0):

```
public OleDbConnection Conn
{
    get
    {
        return this.conn;
    }
}
```

is the same as this:

```
public OleDbConnection GetConn()
{
    return this.conn;
}
```

but just as a property. It's basicly a normal property, without a setter.